# How to append file names to an array - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write a function that iterates over a directory `data_dir` and place the files into one of two arrays, using `contains()`. When I run the following code, I get an empty `r33` array and an `hc` array with all of the file names. I have confirmed that both of the if and else branches are being run. I am quite baffled and I don't understand Matlab (I am a Python user).

```
function[r33, hc] = load_files(data_dir)
    files = dir(fullfile(data_dir,'*.mat'));    
    hc = {};
    r33 = {};
    for i = 1:length(files)
        file = files(i);
        filename = convertCharsToStrings(file.name);
        fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', filename);   
        if contains(filename, "HC")
             hc = [hc, filename];
        else
            r33 = [r33, filename];
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Obviously `contains(filename, "HC")` is always true. Unfortunately we can't debug your code because we don't know what files you have in that directory. I recommend that you replace `files = dir...` with a static array of file names, as a [mre].

Comment: why is `contains(filename, "HC")` always true? My file names are of the pattern "R33_...
" or "HC__..."

Comment: I don't know, but if all file names end up in `hc`, then the `if` condition is always true.

Comment: I would avoid the loop and convertCHars by files = {files(:).name}';

Comment: Show the output. ("Now reading ...")

Comment: Maybe all of your file names have "hc", ex. R33_...hc....mat. Try adding R33 to the if part of the condition